# How to read "echo a | java Class" in Java

Tags: java, system

I need to read somehow "echo a | java Class". I tried

```
public class Class 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I can't find any other solution. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=464749

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read from the [**`stdin`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29), for example, using [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = scanner.next();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have to use `echo a | java Class`, you need to use something like [@João](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12100117/758280)'s answer.

However, if you can change your command and you want to use `args`, you need to use [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs):

```
echo a | xargs java Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

To use:

```
echo Hello | java InputTest
```